# UnauthorizedAccessException While trying to Clear the Cache in xamarin ios

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I get an UnauthorizedAccessException while trying to perform following code in xamarin ios

```
documentsPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
documentsPath = Directory.GetParent(documentsPath).ToString();
InternalAppDataPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "Library");
InternalCacheDataPath = Path.Combine(InternalAppDataPath,"Caches");
  if (Directory.Exists(InternalCacheDataPath))
{
Directory.Delete(InternalCacheDataPath, true);
}
```

While trying to perform the delete function UnauthorizedAccessException is thrown. How can I resolve this?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete that folder path as it is iOS system path. You will get unauthorized exception.

Answer (score 0):

iOS does not allow a user the access directories that are not public, The only directory that you are allowed to make any changes in, Whatsoever is the document directory that is created for your application namely:

```
Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal
```

Now when you do this:

```
documentsPath = Directory.GetParent(documentsPath).ToString();
InternalAppDataPath = Path.Combine(documentsPath, "Library");
InternalCacheDataPath = Path.Combine(InternalAppDataPath,"Caches");
```

And then try to make changes into the parent folder of the document directory since you are not Authorized to access these directories it throws the `UnauthorizedAccessException`.

Now, this is not some sort of permission or something that you can take from the user and make this issue go, It is a restriction by Apple(In my knowledge) and hence you cannot do that.

Good luck

In case of queries feel free to revert.

In case you find some workaround do tell me about it here.